# How to get the title from a child plugin for use in django-cms admin?

Tags: plugins, django-admin, parent-child, django-cms

I´d like to change the plugin title in the admin to the title´s of it´s children.
I want to check it the plugin has children, if true show the titles as it´s title:

I came up to this:

```
class ParentClass(CMSPlugin):

def __unicode__(self):
    inner_content = ""
    if ... >= 1:
        for child in children:
            inner_content += child.title
    else:
        inner_content = "empty"
    return unicode(inner_content)

class ChildClass(CMSPlugin):
title = "X"
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class ParentClass(CMSPlugin):

    def __unicode__(self):
        inner_content = ''

        if self.child_plugin_instances is not None:
            for child in self.child_plugin_instances:
                inner_content += child.title

        inner_content = inner_content or "empty" 
        return unicode(inner_content)
```

Comment: Thank you. To ensure I got the right output I changed it to:

`def __unicode__(self):
        inner_content = []
        
        if self.child_plugin_instances is not None:
            for child in self.child_plugin_instances:
                inner_content.append(child.__unicode__())

        inner_content = ', '.join(inner_content) or "empty"
        return str(inner_content)`